# Use multiple GPUs in TensorFlow to inference with pb model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

I use a server with 8 Titan X, trying to predict image much faster than use a single one GPU.
I load the PB model like this:

```
model_dir = "./model"
    model = "nasnet_large_v1.pb"
    model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, model)
    model_graph = tf.Graph()
    with model_graph.as_default():
        with tf.gfile.GFile(model_path, 'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
            _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
            input_layer = model_graph.get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
            output_layer = model_graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_layer/predictions:0')
```

then I start iterating files in the `./data_input` directory like this:

```
with tf.Session(graph = model_graph, config=config) as inference_session:
        # Initialize session
        initializer = np.zeros([1, 331, 331, 3])
        print("Initialing session...")
        inference_session.run(output_layer, feed_dict={input_layer: initializer})
        print("Done initialing.")

        # Prediction
        file_list = []
        processed_files = []

        for path, dir, files in os.walk('./model_output/processed_files'):
            for file in files:
                processed_files.append(file.split('_')[0]+'.tfrecord')

        print("Processed files: ")
        for f in processed_files:
            print('\t', f)

        while True:
            for path, dir, files in os.walk("./data_input"):
                for file in files:
                    if file == '.DS_Store': continue
                    if file in processed_files: continue
                    print("Reading file {}".format(file))
                    file_path = os.path.join('./data_input', file)
                    file_list.append(file_path)
                    res = predict(file_path)
                    processed_files.append(file)

                    with open('./model_output/processed_files/{}_{}_processed_files.json'.format(file.split('.')[0], model.split('.')[0]), 'w') as f:
                        f.write(json.dumps(processed_files))

                    with open('./model_output/classify_result/{}_{}_classify_result.json'.format(file.split('.')[0], model.split('.')[0]), 'w') as f:
                        f.write(json.dumps(res, indent=4, separators=(',',':')))

            time.sleep(1)
```

in the `predict()` function, I wrote code like this:

```
label_map = get_label()
    # read tfrecord file by tf.data
    dataset = get_dataset(filename)
    # dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.prefetch_to_device("/gpu:0"))
    # load data
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    features = iterator.get_next()

    result = []
    content = {}
    count = 0
    # session
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.global_variables_initializer()
        t1 = time.time()
        try:
            while True:
                [_image, _label, _filepath] = sess.run(fetches=features)
                _image = np.asarray([_image])
                _image = _image.reshape(-1, 331, 331, 3)

                predictions = inference_session.run(output_layer, feed_dict={input_layer: _image})
                predictions = np.squeeze(predictions)

                # res = []
                for i, pred in enumerate(predictions):
                    count += 1
                    overall_result = np.argmax(pred)
                    predict_result = label_map[overall_result].split(":")[-1]

                    if predict_result == 'unknown': continue

                    content['prob'] = str(np.max(pred))
                    content['label'] = predict_result
                    content['filepath'] = str(_filepath[i], encoding='utf-8')
                    result.append(content)

        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            t2 = time.time()
            print("{} images processed, average time: {}s".format(count, (t2-t1)/count))
    return result
```

I tried to use `with tf.device('/gpu:{}'.format(i))` in the loading model part or the inference session part or the session part, `nvidia-smi` shows that only GPU0 is use to 100%, while other GPUs doesn't seem to work even when the memory is load.

What should I do to make all the GPUs run at the same time to boost predicting speed?

My code is under https://github.com/tzattack/image_classification_algorithms .

Answer (score 0):

you can force the device for each node in the graph by:

```
def load_network(graph, i):
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(graph, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    for node in od_graph_def.node:
        node.device = '/gpu:{}'.format(i) if i >= 0 else '/cpu:0'
    return {"od_graph_def": od_graph_def}
```

then you can merge the multiple grapgh you got (per gpu) to one
also change the tensor names in case you are using the same model for all gpus
and run all in one sessoin

works perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follows:

```
def get_frozen_graph(graph_file):
    """Read Frozen Graph file from disk."""
    with tf.gfile.GFile(graph_file, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    return graph_def

trt_graph1 = get_frozen_graph('/home/ved/ved_1/frozen_inference_graph.pb')

with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    [tf_input_l1, tf_scores_l1, tf_boxes_l1, tf_classes_l1, tf_num_detections_l1, tf_masks_l1] = tf.import_graph_def(trt_graph1, 
                    return_elements=['image_tensor:0', 'detection_scores:0', 
                    'detection_boxes:0', 'detection_classes:0','num_detections:0', 'detection_masks:0'])
    
tf_sess1 = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True))

trt_graph2 = get_frozen_graph('/home/ved/ved_2/frozen_inference_graph.pb')

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    [tf_input_l2, tf_scores_l2, tf_boxes_l2, tf_classes_l2, tf_num_detections_l2] = tf.import_graph_def(trt_graph2, 
                    return_elements=['image_tensor:0', 'detection_scores:0', 
                    'detection_boxes:0', 'detection_classes:0','num_detections:0'])
    
tf_sess2 = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True))
```

Comment: This doesn't look like anything is being run in parallel. It looks like you are running sessions on GPUs, one after the next in sequence.

Comment: @jjschuh two separate sessions were created above. Use those sessions in different threads.

Comment: thank you for the tip. By thread, do you mean adding something to the TF graph, or using a separate parallel computing toolbox like "multiprocessing"? I thought TF handled parallel computing.